# Display image bytes in email content message

Tags: java, email, base64, thunderbird

I am trying to show image in email content. It works when I put

```html
<img src='https://someLinkToImage'/>
```

Now instead of link I want to put image bytes.

```java
byte[] imageBytes = Files.readAllBytes(tempImage.toPath())
byte[] encodingImage = Base64.getEncoder().encode(imageBytes);
String saveEncodedString = new String(encodingImage, "UTF-8");
String imgEncoded = """<img src="'data:image/png;base64,${saveEncodedString}'/>"""
```

Later sending it to my desktop email client Mozilla Thunderbird and message content is empty.
Using Groovy and Java in project.

Comment: 1) Why do you believe that `${saveEncodedString}` would insert the content of the `saveEncodedString` variable into the new string? --- 2) Why are you using `"""` to quote a Java string? That won't compile, even in Java 15 where text blocks were added.

Comment: I am writing this code in groovy script. I found that I should give each image CID number and just add it to email attachment. At the end can refer to it in <img> tag.

Comment: If the code is Groovy, why didn't you tag `groovy`?